# What kind of hosting is used for *tube sites?

Tags: hosting, dedicated-hosting

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, and will be happy to remove the Q if needed.

When a site grows from a just-a-fun project to a site with bigger load of visitor, and you want to enable them to upload videos, you might find yourself in a need of a better hosting, including dedicated server and a no-limit web traffic (or some reasonable limit).

So, if people can upload their videos, and if page has around 1000-10000 visitors per day, what kind of hosting is there to choose from? What is needed in that case?

Thx

Comment: Probably better suited on www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a scalable solution.

The term [cloud hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_hosting) comes to mind. Hosting your site in full or in parts (only the large media perhaps) at a cloud provider resolves the problem of the storage limit of servers in the easiest (and cheapest) manner.